# Thermal expansion coefficient times temperature: under which condition is it unity?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

In Landau's Fluid Mechanics p. 8 (2nd edition) he writes for the thermal expansion coefficient $\beta = (1/V) (\partial V/\partial T)_P$:

> For a column of gas in equilibrium which can be taken as a thermodynamically
>   perfect gas, $\beta T = 1$ [...]

This is not not obvious to me. Can somebody provide me with a derivation or an argument under which circumstances I can approximate this expression like that?

Or is it as easy as taking Clapeyron's equation for $V$, i.e. $PV = NT \implies V = NT/P$, so that we get
$$
\beta T = \frac{TN}{VP} = 1
$$

This leaves me somehow unsatisfied; is there maybe a more physical argument for this?

Answer (score 1):

Start with an ideal gas,
$$
V=\frac{nRT}p
$$
Then take the natural logarithm of this:
$$
\ln V=\ln T+\ln\frac{nR}{p}
$$
The derivative of both sides with respect to $T$ gives
$$
\frac{d\ln V}{dT}=\frac{d\ln T}{dT}+\frac{d\ln\frac{nR}{p}}{dT}=\frac{d\ln T}{dT}=\frac{1}{T}
$$
where we assume an isobaric situation so that $p$ contributes nothing.

The left hand side is also equal to
$$
\frac{d\ln V}{dT}=\frac1V\frac{dV}{dT}=\beta
$$
Thus, for an ideal gas we have
$$
\beta=\frac{1}{T}
$$
This simply means that the temperature-dependent thermal expansion coefficient increases at lower temperatures and decreases at higher temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

What he writes down is the relative change in volume with temperature, so it is true by definition. What may be confusing is that sometimes β denotes the thermal expansion coefficient in **two** dimensions, whereas the three-dimensional coefficient is meant here.